# How to insert data from JSON to javascript function?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm very new in javascript and I try to find problem for a week.

My example code like below (all are in a html page in head tag)

//example function 1

```
    function randomString(len, charSet) {
            charSet = charSet || 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
            var randomString = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var randomPoz = Math.floor(Math.random() * charSet.length);
            randomString += charSet.substring(randomPoz,randomPoz+1);
        }
            return randomString;
    }



//example function 2
        function tests(randomString) {

                alert(randomString);

        }

//example function 3 pull data from JSON to div id test

        $(document).ready(function() { 
           $.getJSON("http://www.test.com/get_json_data.php?", {
                    cat_id: "3",
                    type:'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
              }, function(data) {
                    $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {


                    $('#test').append('<a href="#" onclick="tests(randomString(5))"><img src="http://www.test.com/images/'+item.image+'"/></a>'); 

                  if (i == 10) return false;
                   });
              });
           });
```

My Problem is I wan to insert var from JSON for example "item.id" in to "onclick" what's I tried to do is below

**onclick="tests(randomString(5)+item.id)"**

the result I wan to see is alert 5 random chars and include item.id at the end for example

```
xIyax33 (33 is item.id)
TwQpu34 (34 is item.id)
AERim35 (35 is item.id)
```

But always show error "item is not defined"

How can I change the code to insert var from JSON ?

Comment: `$('#test').append('<a href="#" onclick="tests(randomString('+item.id+'))"><img src="http://www.test.com/images/' + item.image + '"/></a>');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add one more parameter in your `randomString()` function called `id` which will fetch the `item.id`. And you need to append it to your `randomString`.

```
function randomString(len,id, charSet) {//See second param
     charSet = charSet || 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
     var randomString = '';
     for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         var randomPoz = Math.floor(Math.random() * charSet.length);
         randomString += charSet.substring(randomPoz, randomPoz + 1);
     }
     return randomString+id; //+id
 }
```

And change your append to

```
$('#test').append('<a href="#" onclick="tests(randomString(5,'+item.id+'))"><img src="http://www.test.com/images/'+item.image+'"/></a>');
```

Comment: Work like charm I'm really thank you you to help me.